# Does mana stay in your mana pool after the land has been destroyed

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I tap a bunch of land and then it gets destroyed **after** I tapped it, does the mana stay in my mana pool?

Comment: Be careful not to associate lands and mana too closely. Tapping a land happens to be the most common way to produce mana, but not all lands produce mana, and there are other ways to produce mana other than lands.

Comment: Unless any cards explicitly say otherwise, things in mtg like mana, abilities, damage, and so on, usually exists independently of, and doesn't really care about, its source. Once it has been brought into existence, it is its own entity.

Answer (score 11):

**Yes, it will stay in your mana pool until the end of the current step or phase.**

There are effects that empty your mana pool, but they specifically say so, such as [Mana Short](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMana%20Short%5d).

> 106.4. When an effect produces mana, that mana goes into a player’s mana pool. From there, it can be used to pay costs immediately, or it can stay in the player’s mana pool. Each player’s mana pool empties at the end of each step and phase.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes.

Once mana has been added to your mana pool it will remain there until the end of each step unless you choose to spend it to pay a cost.

Comment: "end of the round" is incorrect

Comment: @Hamsterrific Whoops. Apparently I was more tired than I thought when I typed this up.  Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1):

The land is tapped for mana and that mana is available until the end of the current phase or step.

For example, the Combat phase has several steps.

> The combat phase is the third phase in a turn, and has five steps in this >order:
>
> Beginning of Combat Step
>
> Declare Attackers Step
>
> etc...

Mana tapped, then the land being destroyed sounds unlikely to happen all in a single phase or step, as land destruction is often sorcery speed. You would have to be tapping on opponent's turn, or they have instant speed destruction, but yes, the mana stays until end of the step, within the phase.

Answer (score -1):

I can go into a really long, technical explanation of how/why but the short answer is yes. Yes, the Mana stays in your mana pool until the end of the step/phase the lands are tapped in.

Comment: Hackworth's answer already gives the (not so) long, technical explanation.  I don't think this answer adds anything that the other answers didn't already cover.